# Comparing dates in Core Data query using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

My Core Data model has an NSDate attribute like here:

```
@interface DBVial : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * updated_at;
```

How can I get the most recent (according to updated_at) record from all of the records of DBVial? Can I perform it by using NSPredicate? 
I know I could fetch all of them and then sort them and get the first one but is it possible to use only NSPredicate instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. No need to use `NSPredicate`, instead set the `NSFetchRequest`'s `sortDescriptor` to sort records by date, and `fetchLimit` so you get only the most recent record. Like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DBVial" 
                             inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedObjectContext];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"updated_at" ascending:NO]];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
NSError *error = nil;

DBVial *mostRecent =  [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
```